# Transform data using scala in spark

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, apache-spark, sdk, java-7

I am trying to transform the input text file into a Key/Value RDD, but the code below doesn't work.(The text file is a tab separated file.) I am really new to Scala and Spark so I would really appreciate your help.

```
import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext}
import scala.io.Source

object shortTwitter {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    for (line <- Source.fromFile(args(1).txt).getLines()) {
      val newLine = line.map(line =>
      val p = line.split("\t")
      (p(0).toString, p(1).toInt)
      )
}

    val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("ShortTwitterAnalysis").setMaster("local[2]")
    val sc = new SparkContext(sparkConf)
    val text = sc.textFile(args(0))
    val counts = text.flatMap(line => line.split("\t"))
  }
}
```

Comment: "code below doesn't work" - how so? What's the failure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you want the resulting RDD to have the type `RDD[(String, Int)]`, so -

- You should use `map` (which transforms each record into a single new record) and not `flatMap` (which transform each record into *multiple* records)
- You should map the result of the `split` into a tuple

Altogether:

```
val counts = text
  .map(line => line.split("\t"))
  .map(arr => (arr(0), arr(1).toInt))
```

**EDIT** per clarification in comment: if you're also interested in fixing the non-Spark part (which reads the file sequentially), you have some errors in the for-comprehension syntax, here's the entire thing:

```
def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
  // read the file without Spark (not necessary when using Spark):
  val countsWithoutSpark: Iterator[(String, Int)] = for {
    line <- Source.fromFile(args(1)).getLines()
  } yield {
    val p = line.split("\t")
    (p(0), p(1).toInt)
  }

  // equivalent code using Spark:
  val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("ShortTwitterAnalysis").setMaster("local[2]")
  val sc = new SparkContext(sparkConf)
  val counts: RDD[(String, Int)] = sc.textFile(args(0))
    .map(line => line.split("\t"))
    .map(arr => (arr(0), arr(1).toInt))
}
```

Comment: Besides that, the error says 'illegal start of simple expression, val p = line.split("\t")'. Because of this error I cannot run the code at all

Comment: Oh I see, I thought that code was just meant to clarify what you're trying to do with Spark, I see no sense in using both parts - one reads the file sequentially and one uses Spark to do the same thing... Anyway - see updated answer.

Comment: Thank you! The second part was the code to do something else. Sorry for the confusion lol.. and one more question! How can I check the result of codes without spark using 'print' ?

Comment: `countsWithoutSpark.foreach(println)`